# How can I get weekly post from mysql database in codeigniter framework

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

How can I get weekly post from mysql database in codeigniter framework. I can not understand that how to do that and what is the logic?
My database table is :

```
id  | post_schedule_date  | post_name   |  post_description
-----------------------------------------------------------
1   | 29-06-2014          | Test title  |  Test description
-----------------------------------------------------------
2   | 30-06-2014          | Test title  |  Test description
-----------------------------------------------------------
3   | 01-07-2014          | Test title  |  Test description
-----------------------------------------------------------
4   | 02-07-2014          | Test title  |  Test description
-----------------------------------------------------------
5   | 02-07-2014          | Test title  |  Test description
-----------------------------------------------------------
6   | 03-07-2014          | Test title  |  Test description
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I want the output like :

Current Week (5)
Previous Week (2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Selects Current Week records 
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE post_schedule_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY ) 
AND created_at < curdate() + 1  ;

//Selects Previous week
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE post_schedule_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY ) 
AND created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY ) ;
```

Here 'post_schedule_date' is your column name , make sure this is the col where you put your current date as you enter a record in the database.